# Custom typeface for dialog's title

Tags: android, dialog, typeface

In an application I'm building, I'm trying to systematically change the font of every piece of text to a custom font.  Does anyone know whether it's possible to apply styles such as custom typefaces to the title of a dialog?

So far, I haven't been able to find a way, and so my best bet seems to be to use an AlertDialog, and just use a textview as my title in a layout that I inflate.  This is a bit long winded, so if there's a direct way to customize the style of the dialog's title, that would save some time!

Answer (score 0):

Try using/inheriting `DialogWindowTitle` and/or `@style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle`.

See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

Comment: unfortunately you can't set a custom typeface in XML (as far as I've been able to tell, anyway), so I'm not sure that'll help..